# How can I mysqldump a table with SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to dump a table, but with masked emails, not as it is.

```
mysql -h <ip> -u <username> -P <port> -p --execute="
SELECT
    au.id,
    CASE WHEN (au.email NOT LIKE '%@abcd.com%' AND au.email NOT LIKE '%@abcd_test.com%') THEN CONCAT('user+', u.id, '@abcd_test.com') ELSE au.email END as email,
    au.user_id
    FROM <dbname>.<tablename> as au
    LEFT JOIN <dbname>.<tablename2> as u
" > ~/<tablename>.sql
```

I tried running this command, but it doesn't create a dump that can be imported.

Actually, there are couple other tables that have email columns that need to be masked similarly, and ideally I'd like to have a dump of the whole database with emails anonymized like this.

If that's not possible, I'd at least want to have a dump of a table with masked emails like the output from above shell command that can be imported separately into mysql database.

How can I dump a table with SELECT query? or can I import the output of the above command?

This is a production database, so I want to avoid creating a new table on this database or doing anything that can possibly mess up this database.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'dump.sql' from `table_name` where `condition`

Comment: This file cannot be imported.